# Error installing Ruby 3.1.2 on macOS 12.5

Tags: ruby, ruby-install

I'm trying to install Ruby 3.1.2 on macOS 12.5, using chruby as my version manager.

Running `ruby-install ruby`, I get this error:

```
>>> Extracting ruby-3.1.2.tar.xz to /Users/justin/src/ruby-3.1.2 ...
/usr/local/bin/../share/ruby-install/util.sh: line 56: xzcat: command not found
/usr/local/bin/ruby-install: line 46: cd: /Users/justin/src/ruby-3.1.2: No such file or directory
>>> Regenerating ./configure script ...
autoreconf: error: 'configure.ac' is required
!!! Configuration of ruby 3.1.2 failed!
```

I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot this. Anybody have some tips for me?

Answer (score 13):

There seems to be [an issue in ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/429) tracking this.

I appears that ruby-install currently does not explicitly depend on `xz` as a dependency although they are required for chruby and ruby-install. Until the new version of ruby-install is fully available on homebrew, you can manually install the `xz` package with

```
brew install xz
```

to make sure `xz` (and thus the `xzcat` executable) are available on your system. Afterwards, you should be able to install your Ruby version.